# Theorems using polyglossia, llncs and french language

Tags: polyglossia, lncs

I would like to use the llncs style for definition, theorems and the like while using polyglossia for typesetting.
But when I use both of them, the llncs style will stay in english, instead of french.

MWE (llncs v2.20, compiled with XeLaTeX):

```latex
\documentclass[francais]{llncs}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}

\begin{document}

\begin{remark}

\end{remark}

\end{document}
```

I would like to have the same result as when removing the `usepackage` and `setmainlanguage` lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reset the non-English names after loading `polyglossia`, using the `\switcht@[somelanguage]` macros defined by the `llncs` class. Because these macros contains an `@` symbol in the name you have to surround the macro call by `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` (see [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do)).

MWE:

```
\documentclass[francais]{llncs}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}
\makeatletter
\switcht@francais
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{remark}

\end{remark}

\end{document}
```